# How to get datarow cell value with column name datatable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, sqldatareader, sqldataadapter

Let Me first tell you what i am doing right now and what problem i am facing.

Right now i am using `SqlDataReader` for fetching data from database my function looks like

```
 public List<TOPIC_REPORT> gettopicreports()
        {
            query = "SELECT * FROM [Topic Reports]";
            List<TOPIC_REPORT> rpl = new List<TOPIC_REPORT>();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                sdr = com.ExecuteReader();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    rt = new TOPIC_REPORT();
                    rt.ContentId = sdr.GetString(0);
                    rt.TimesReported = sdr.GetInt64(1);
                    rt.IsBanned = sdr.GetInt32(2);
                    rpl.Add(rt);

                }
                con.Close();
                return rpl;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                con.Close();
                throw e;
            }
        }
```

Problems with above code

1. Need to assign values to class variables on by one and problematic  with multiple select query.
2. Need to take care of ResultSet , while loop etc.

Above Problem solution use SqlDataAdapter.

```
public DataSet getdata()
        {
            com.CommandText = "GetMasterPageData";
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            return ds;
        }
```

This solves above stated problems but

1. Decrease my prog readability because my front end person don't know in which order i am sending DataTables in DataSet.
2. Don't know order of selected values in DataTable.
3. Front end person need to work on column index which is at end will be problematic.

Suggest me what should i do to solve above stated problems.

Comment: Are you saying that in the first code block you want to return multiple result sets? Your query looks as if it will only return one. If you are wanting to return multiple result sets, do they all have the same columns?

Comment: I need to return multiple result set with different columns.

Comment: @HotCoolStud Please share your StoredProcedure

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query to return multiple result sets, by combining all your queries. For example:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM [Topic Reports]; SELECT * FROM [Other table]";
```

After iterating the first result set with SqlDataReader.Read, use SqlDataReader.NextResultSet() method to get to the second result, then use SqlDataReader.Read to iterate the second set.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.nextresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As a side note, if you do this, then you will have to figure out a way of returning collections of two types of objects from your method. It would probably be better to just use 1 method to get a collection of object A, and a different method to get a collection of object B.